# Is there an gpg module for erlang?

Tags: erlang, gnupg

I want to write a programm, which does a lot of things like decrypt and crypt messages or search key servers for gpg keys. Is there any gpg modulde/libary for erlang?
or if not how can i  do this in erlang whithout writing an gpg erlang module? I searched the internet, but i didn´t found anything. or a way to use gpgme?

Thank you

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only thing I could find: [sa2ajj/egpgme](https://github.com/sa2ajj/egpgme)